# How to add listview and tabbarview in a page in flutter

Tags: listview, flutter

I want to create a web page with flutter. Left page area has a listview, right page has tabbarview. If any listview item was preesed, tabbarview will be changed. 
Can anyone give me some advice? Thank you.

Comment: what you tried so far?

Comment: Do you want to create a pageview with 2 pages or single view with 2 views inside it ?

Comment: If you would like to receive help, you should share your code and ask a specific question. Follow the guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you all. Currently I use a Row widget, and a listview a column inside the row. I will ask a specific question with code in another thread.